# Executing Swift code while app is not open

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, realm

I want to be able to run a timer ever 5 seconds to continually use the locationManager to find the location and get information from an external JSON API using functions from another class, weather.swift, and add this information to a Realm database. I have got all of this to work in the foreground, but I do not know how to get it to work in the background. I enabled the background capabilities and allowed working in the background in the info.plist.

Using the **AppDelegate**, I was able to to figure out a little bit on how to work with the app in the background while testing the **applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication)** function. I was able to print and execute lines of code once right when the app was exited, but when I tried to set a timer and continually get the location, fetch data from the API, and add this new info to the Realm database, it would not work. In addition, we needed to push notifications when something changed in the **detectChange()** function. The push notifications seemed like they worked while the app wasn't running, however.

Problems:

- The locationManager would not work properly. I did not really know how to get this to work in the background while the app was not open.
- I did not know how to get the timer to continually run while the app was not running. It would not work at all.

ViewController.swift:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:                  [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        let lat = locValue.latitude
        let long = locValue.longitude
        latitude = lat
        longitude = long
        print("\(latitude) \(longitude)")

    if((longitude != 0.0) && (latitude != 0.0)){
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        weatherLabel.text = "\(weather.temperature(latitude, longitude: longitude))°"
        cityLabel.text = weather.city(latitude, longitude: longitude)
        currentInfo.locationz = weather.city(latitude, longitude: longitude)
        windSpeedLabel.text = "\(weather.windSpeed(latitude, longitude: longitude)) mph"
        self.windDirectionImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat(90 + weather.windDirection(latitude, longitude: longitude)) * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)
        setImage(weather.icon(latitude, longitude: longitude))


        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: #selector(UIMenuController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

func update(){
    let instance = Instance()
    addInstance(instance, timestamp: currentInfo.time(), temperature: weather.temperature(latitude, longitude: longitude), windSpeed: weather.windSpeed(latitude, longitude: longitude), windDirection: weather.windDirection(latitude, longitude: longitude), location: weather.city(latitude, longitude: longitude), condition: weather.description(latitude, longitude: longitude),icon: weather.icon(latitude, longitude: longitude))
    detectChange()
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to do that off of that delegate method, you will need to run a background process and setup the capabilities of your app to be allowed to run in the background

Comment: I have already set all the capabilities to allow the app to run in the background. How would I run a background process without using that delegate method? @bolnad

Comment: here's a tutorial on it https://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial